# how to get String array containing distinct characters?

Tags: java, for-loop, set

i have a String **"iye"** and i want make it distinct and also i have a **array ["hi", "bye", "bebe"]** and i want to make each element of the array and get the distinct characters only so my array would be like this **["hi", "bye", "be"]** an then at last i want to take each element from that distinct array and count how many characters of **distinctArray[i]** are present in the distinct String **"iye"** and i will store that count for each element of distinct array in same order respectively to the elements of distinct array for e.g

**sample input = "iyee" and ["hi", "bye", "bebe"]**

**sample ouput = [1, 2, 1]**

below is my solution not working for larger inputs

```
      static int[] mathProfessor(String B,String[] a){
      List<String> distinct = new ArrayList<String>();
      int[] arr = new int[a.length];

      // store each value of names array as distinct value
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        a[i].chars().distinct().forEach(c -> str.append((char) c));
        distinct.add(str.toString());
      }
      // System.out.println("distinct list: " + distinct.toString());

      // store the count
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < distinct.size(); i++) {
        String s = distinct.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length(); j++) {
          if (s.contains(Character.toString(B.charAt(j))))
            count++;
        }
        arr[i] = count;
        count = 0;
      }

      return arr;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working for larger inputs"

Comment: you better divide your problem in some steps and divide the code accordingly - for example one method to find the distinct characters (remove duplicates), another to count how many of the characters of one string is in another, ... so it is much easier to test each part independently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int[] mathProfessor(String b, String[] a) {
    b = dist(b);
    int count = 0;
    String[] arr = new String[a.length];
    int[] countArr = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = dist(a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
        if (arr[i].contains(Character.toString(b.charAt(j))))
          count++;
      }
      countArr[i] = count;
      count = 0;
    }

    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(countArr));
    return countArr;
  }

  public static String dist(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (set.add(s.charAt(i)) == true)
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8+ Streams:

```java
    static int[] mathProfessor(String b, String[] a) {

        var distinctB = dist(b);
        System.out.println(distinctB);
        var result = new int[a.length];

        for(int i=0, j=a.length; i < j; i++) {
            result[i] = (int) Arrays.stream(dist(a[i]).split("")).filter(distinctB::contains).count();
        }

        return result;

      }
    
      public static String dist(String s) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(s.split("")));
        return String.join("", set);
        
      }
```